# Java Program for Windows 7 & Windows 10

Tags: java, windows

I'd like to write a desktop app using Java and I'm wondering if I can get the app to execute on computers running both Window 7 and Windows 10. I've got Eclipse set up with JavaSE 1.8 and I'm running Windows 8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Once it's compiled, you can pass your app on to any computer with a JVM (Java virtual machine, aka "any machine with java installed") and your application will be able to be run. There are versioning caveats, for instance an old version JVM won't be able to run newer code (compiled to a higher version) but you probably won't have to worry about it. If you need to, you can set your compiler to compile to earlier versions (and you can set this in eclipse) but you probably won't have to bother with it.